# Query to return values from more then 6 months ago

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

this is the code it have so far

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE User_Last_Login> ");
```

the format for user_last_login is yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE User_Last_Login < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE User_Last_Login < NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE User_Last_Login < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Comment: Should be `less than`, not `greater than`